# Twelve fair dice are rolled at random. Calculate the probability that each number 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 appears exactly twice

Tags: probability

Ok so my effort:

(1/6)^12 is the probability of getting exactly 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6 in that order

I know you need to consider using choose, but I have no idea which one to use here. 
12Choose?? .

Answer (score 2):

Your effort is okay, and you should wonder now: "how many orders  exist such that every number in $\{1,\dots,6\}$ occurs twice?"

The answer on that is $$\binom{12}{2,2,2,2,2,2}:=\frac{12!}{2!2!2!2!2!2!}$$

---

You are dealing here with [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution).

There are $12$ independent experiments that have $6$ equiprobable outcomes (in stead of $2$ as in the binomial case).

The probability you mention equals:$$6^{-12}\frac{12!}{2!2!2!2!2!2!}$$

Answer (score 1):

You have to multiply your answer by the number of rearrangements of 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6 to finish. That is $12!/(2^6)$ using multinomial coefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Good so far. Now if the string was $1,2,\cdots, 12$ you could permute it in $12!$ ways, while applying that to a string with $6 couples, each couple will be counted twice.  So ..